# How to form " less than or equal to " statement in ATG using dsp tag library?

Tags: atg

Im currently developing an e-commerce site for a cellular network in ATG. I'm trying to apply "filters" to restrict phones according to their display sizes with three categories namely

1. 4 -inches and less
2. 4 - 5 inches
3. 5 - inches and more.

Currently I am able to pass only one value like 4 inches and get all phones in the 4 inch category.

--------code---------

```
<LI id=menu-item-458
                                                       class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-458">
                                                       <dsp:droplet name="/store/commerce/droplets/FilterDroplet" >
                                                       <dsp:param name="filterBy" value="displayScreenDetails"/>
                                                       <dsp:param name="filterConstant" value="4"/>
                                                       <dsp:oparam name="output">
                                                       <p id="4" class="selected">
<A href="#"onclick="filterItems('displayScreenDetails','4')">* 4-inches(<dsp:valueof param="count"/>)</A></p>`
                                                        </dsp:oparam>
                                                        </dsp:droplet>
                                                    </LI>
```

---

Its an `<LI>` for showing the menu with passing values to a script function called filerItems()

I wanna show all phones under their respective categories and not definitive numbers. Help me form the code with dsp tag libraries or a java method to handle the passed value.
I hope my question is clear. 
Thank you.!

Comment: Post your `FilterDroplet` source for some more help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add another request parameter to your `FilterDroplet` that will take an operator (like 'equals' or 'lessThan') and then, inside the `service` method call a new method that takes 3 parameters. Assuming that you currently have a small method that will take 2 parameters (for 'filterBy' and 'filterConstant').

Your output also seems a bit restricted, since it assumes you will only get 1 result. There is no loop running over the output param.

Answer (score 0):

There are easy ways and long ways to do this. But I would recommend the long way which will help in a long run. Since you are working with filters, its important to categorize them with the SKU property. Hoping that screen size comes from BCC (meaning DB), try to create a field for your SKU object to compute the category during the initialization.

SKU will already have your screen size property and it shouldn't be hard enough to create a field for filter in your non-repository SKU object. While page is loading, pass all the SKUs displayed on page and get the filter details, so that it will be helpful later if another filter item is added.

I feel it needs a more generic approach by creating a custom Filter map, which can be used for populating any property.